# UITextFieldDelegate protocol changed between iOS 4.3 and 5.0. What's happening?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uitextfielddelegate

Seems to be undocumented changes in how UITextFieldDelegate protocol works between iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.0 which are breaking my code.

Simple to reproduce as follows:
Using XCode 4.2, create a 'Single View Application' project called test. Use default options (i.e. no Storyboard, but yes to ARC)
Set deployment target to 4.3 (so we can run the app in both 5.0 and 4.3)

Put this code in the ViewController.h header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,strong) UITextField *textField1;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITextField *textField2;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel *resultsLabel;

@end
```

Put this in the ViewController.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textField1,textField2,resultsLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    textField1=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30)];
    textField1.tag=1;
    textField1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    textField1.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField1];

    textField2=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 30)];
    textField2.tag=2;
    textField2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    textField2.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField2];

    resultsLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 300, 30)];
    resultsLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:resultsLabel];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 1:
            // textField1
            [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
            resultsLabel.text=@"Finished editing 1st box";
            break;

        case 2:
            // textField2
            resultsLabel.text=@"Finished editing 2nd box";
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

Run the code in the simulator and it displays two white UITextFields. Tap the first one, then tap the second one.

If run in iOS 4.3 on the simulator the UILabel displays "Finished editing 1st box"
If run in iOS 5.0 on the simulator the UILabel displays "Finished editing 2nd box"

I am trying to make it so that when you leave field i you automatically go to field (i+1). Any suggestions as to what's wrong, and how to fix it? I can't see any mention in Apple's iOS 5 release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By touching the second box its automatically becoming the first responder so setting it progmatically is setting it twice.

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField  == textField2) {

        resultsLabel.text=@"Finished editing 2nd box";
    }
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if (textField == textField2) {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        if (textField == textField2) {
        resultsLabel.text=@"Finished editing 1st box";

    }
}
```

This will work and it will automatically switch first responder by hitting return.

Comment: There is a problem with this approach:How do you want to dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: Thanks v much (accepted as correct answer :-) The actual code I'm writing also responds to textFieldShouldReturn so if you tap 'enter' on field1 you automatically go to field2 - hence the need to programmatically set it at some point. Odd that iOS4.3 and 5.0 do this differently - some kind of undocumented feature I guess. As if 4.3 resigns firstResponder from the textField, whereas 5.0 just resigns firstResponder from whatever has it..... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is being called twice.

Once when you select textField2 (which ends the editing in textField1) and then again when you call `[textField2 becomeFirstResponder];`: Since textField2 it is already the firstResponder (because you touched it in order to end the editing on textField1) when you tell it to become the firstResponder again, it actually resigns it's firstResponder status (which invokes `textFieldDidEndEditing`) and then becomes the firstResponder again.

Try this changing `[textField2 becomeFirstResponder];` to this:

```
 if (![textField2 isFirstResponder]) {
      [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: @Inafziger - Thanks for the good idea. Just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't make any difference... I'll have to do some more subtle testing and breakpointing...

Comment: Actually, textField2 probably isn't the firstResponder YET, but it is in the queue already so will still get called twice.  If you just remove the [textField2 becomesFirstResponder]; altogether, does it work properly when you tap the second text field?

Comment: @Inafziger - the problem comes back if I remove the becomesFirstResponder because in my (larger) form, you can exit field 1 by tapping 'Done' on the keyboard, which should also automatically pass focus to field 2. If I don't have that in there, then leaving field 1 just dismisses the keyboard, which isn't what I'm after. I'm particularly interested in why the difference between iOS4.3 and iOS5.0 as I worry that I'm coding 'against the grain' of the SDK, and will hit other problems later if I don't understand why Apple has introduced this new behaviour into iOS5.0.... Thanks for the answering:)